# UITableView reloads data, when pushing a new viewController

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, uiviewcontroller, uinavigationcontroller

I have the following VC hierarchy: ParentViewController -> Navigation Controller(child VC) -> ViewController(with UITableView).

I am meeting the following issue:
In UITableViewDelegate.didSelectRowAtIndexPath, the app is pushing a new ViewController on the stack. The problem is that at this stage, the table view is automatically reloaded, without any explicit call to reloadData. This fact creates several issues, for example on return to the screen(with Back button) the table view is scrolled at the beginning instead of being focused on the selected row.

Could you please help me find why is it doing like so, is it a bug, or how to fix the issue?

**UPDATE:** I have just tested the same case on iOS 7.1 and there is no issue like that, I mean pushing a viewController, than poping back to the viewController containing the UITableView does not loose focus of the selected row.
[image]

Comment: If you are using UITableViewController then set, clearselectiononviewwillappear to NO. Or else you might have to keep track of the selected row and when viewWillAppear trigger, set it selected and sroll it to the visible point.

Comment: It's not a UITableViewController. For the other case, the architecture of the app, can't allow me perform that in viewWillAppear. I have also tried in viewDidAppear, but visually it's not ok.

Comment: Are you just pushing/popping the view controller?  Any custom segue or transition?  That stack trace seems to suggest that the TV is changing window, and is consequently resizing, which triggers the reload.

Comment: I'm just pushing a view controller

Comment: I am also getting same issue, when I tried to push to a view controller it's reloading current screen table view with out calling reloadData. Did you find any solution or any reason why it's happening like this?

Comment: Nope :) I think it's something on the Apple side.

Answer (score 0):

hope this could help you.

My solution is to use navigationviewcontroller delegate, save selection when will push another one, and set back when pop back.

My sample code(I have set table view controller as delegate)

```
static NSIndexPath* path = nil;

- (void)navigationController:(UINavigationController *)navigationController willShowViewController:(UIViewController *)viewController animated:(BOOL)animated
{
    if (viewController == self)
    {
        [self.tableView reloadData];
        [self.tableView selectRowAtIndexPath:path animated:NO scrollPosition:UITableViewScrollPositionMiddle];
    }
}

- (void)navigationController:(UINavigationController *)navigationController didShowViewController:(UIViewController *)viewController animated:(BOOL)animated
{
     path = self.tableView.indexPathForSelectedRow;
}
```

Comment: I don't think setting a NSIndexPath as static is a good idea.

Comment: Sure, you could set anything you want in your code, it just a concept to solve such kind of problem, so my key point is to use delegate to avoid tableview's mechanism in iOS8, not the way to set a variable.